# Stopwatch Program PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt

I have this code taken from a youtube video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP7CaRg9OPA&t=1104s.
It is a Stopwatch program, that allows you to Start, Stop, Reset, and Lap. But every time I click the start button, the mouse pointer has the loading circle, and then the app closes itself. Slightly confused, anyone have any advice?

Here is my code.

```
import time
import thread6

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("stopwatch.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.running = False
        self.started = False

        self.passed = 0
        self.previous_passed = 0
        self.lap = 1

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_stop)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.lap_reset)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("border: 10px solid transparent")

    def start_stop(self):
        if self.running:
            self.running = False
            self.pushButton.setText("Resume")
            self.pushButton_2.setText("Reset")
        else:
            self.running = True
            self.pushButton.setText("Stop")
            self.pushButton_2.setText("Lap")
            self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
            threading.Thread(target=self.stopwatch).start()

    def lap_reset(self):
        pass

    def format_time_string(self, time_passed):
        secs = time_passed % 60
        mins = time_passed // 60
        hours = mins // 60
        return f"{int(hours):02d}:{int(mins):02d}:{int(secs):02d}:{int((self.passed % 1) * 100):02d}"


    def stopwatch(self):
        start = time.time()
        if self.started:
            until_now = self.passed
        else:
            until_now = 0
            self.started = True

        while self.running:
            self.passed = time.time() - start + until_now
            self.label.setText(self.format_time_string(self.passed))



def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyGUI()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There is a typo that I can see in the code `self.bushButton_2.setEnabled(True)` should be changed to `pushButton_2`, secondly that import of `import thread6` should be changed to `import threading`.

Comment: Good spot, but didn't change anything lol

Comment: Have you tried changing the import?

Comment: Which one are you talking about

Comment: The one I mentioned in my first comment `thread6` to `threading`

Comment: Yes that worked and timer is now starting

Comment: That's the problem with youtube tutorials: their authors are more interested in views than in actually checking the validity of what they provide, since they just play around with a toolkit or library and they assume they're experienced enough to create a tutorial. Spoiler alert, they **never** are. Widgets are **not** thread safe, and accessing a widget from a thread is **completely** unsafe and plain wrong: the program is bound to crash sooner or later. It's also completely wrong to use a while loop for that without at least a basic sleep function, also considering the final time resolution.

Comment: Can you explain further on what to do? @musicamante

Comment: @JackLythgoe Use QTimer with a 10ms interval and QElapsedTimer to get the time elapsed since the watch was started.